# Show only a specified sub-region in a matplotlib contour plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, contourf

Am using matplotlib's contourf to do some contour plotting.  I would like the contour plot to be filled with a particular sub-region of the data I want to display, leaving the rest of the data out of the picture.  Is there a way to do this with contourf?

The xlim/ylim keywords do not help.  No error returned, but no effect on the contour plot.  Same with the "extent" keyword.  Giving contourf just a subsection to plot is not an option (not an easy option, I should say) because my data is on an irregular grid.

Comment: Please include your code.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone's interested, it turns out it's pretty easy.  I do the contour and then I set x and y limits with matplotlib.pyplot.xlim and ylim:

```
contourf(x,y,z)
xlim((1000,2000))
ylim((4000,7000))
```